# How do I initialize a gem (guard-rspec) from inside of rubymine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubygems, rubymine, guard

I'm n00b at rails so I may be missing something that is completely obvious :)

I just installed the guard-rspec gem with bundle install but I need to initialize it in RubyMine.

i.e.

bundle exec guard init rspec

For the life of me I can't figure out how to do this with out opening a command prompt (which I know how to do) which defeats part of the reason to use RubyMine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found:

https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Run-guard-with-Rubymine

which states:

EDIT: It turns out that running

```
exec "guard"
```

will initialize itself in rubymine as well as run the tests as they are defined.

Where as the following command (now edited to be the correct one) will just initialize the guardfile.

> Rubymine 3.2.4 works w/ guard, althought the only way to run it is using a run_guard.rb at the project > root with 1 line:
>
> ```
> exec "guard init rspec"
> ```
>
> And then run Cmd + ALt + F8 to run this file from Rubymine.

Though for windows I just right clicked on run_guard.rb and hit run, which appears to work correctly.